# Script (ArcPy) vs field calculator (Python Parser) behaviour of getPart in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, error-999999, python-parser

From time to time I have to access geometry field and shuffle through points in it. Process is simple:

1. Get shape
2. Get it's part
3. Iterate through part's points

This is how it looks like in a script

```
import arcpy
fc = r'd:\scratch\line.shp'
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,"Shape@") as cursor:
   for row in cursor:
      shp=row[0]
      part=shp.getPart(0)
      for p in part:
         print p.X
```

However, when I try to do similar thing using field calculator:

```
def plineM(shp):
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 for p in part:
  return p.X

plineM( !Shape! )
```

I got 999999 error.

To make it work I am forced to a) define the length of an array and b) use getObject() method to access the point:

```
def plineM(shp):
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 n=len(part)
 for i in xrange(n):
  p=part.getObject(i)
  return p.X
```

Question: why simple array iterator works in script and does not work in field calculator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With cursors and the `"SHAPE@"` token, a geometry object is returned. The `getPart()` method returns an [Array](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/array.htm) containing all the points for that particular part.

Interestingly, field calculator also returns a geometry object, but the `getPart()` method does not appear to return an array, although it is something similar. Maybe an unpacked array?

Luckily, arcpy can be accessed inside field calculator, so it's a simple call to `arcpy.Array()`:

```py
def plineM(shp):
  for part in arcpy.Array(shp.getPart(0)):
    for p in part:
      return None if p is None else p.X          

plineM(!Shape!)
```

Comment: It seems getPart() in FC does return array, because getObject() is very 'array' method. Script on the other hand converts array to something like list. +1 anyway, I never though I can use arcpy without import arcpy in calculator

Comment: I am accepting it because you confirmed my observation, that calculator and script do return different objects. I hit the wall yesterday trying to figure this

Comment: This will fail on a polygon interior ring (_"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'X'"_). This seems to work: `for p in part: if p: return p.X`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it works in a script because you are explicitly getting the `Shape@` field.

If you run into a feature with a null shape, your first field calculator will try to unpack it and run into an error.

Comment: What do I access in field calculator with !Shape!  ?