# Create list of [X, Y] coordinates within field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

Lately i've been working on a script that must calculate a value in ArcGIS field calculator based on all vertex coordinates of a polyline. But i am struggling to create a list of a polylines coordinates whitin the field calculator. The list is not meant to fill the field values, but it make other calculations possible.

This is how the list must be like:

```
coordinates = [[534359.1787999999, 6944339.3809], [534298.1876999997, 6944310.3992], [534282.0721000005, 6944304.4425]]
```

I have found [some material about it on ArcGIS Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001t000000), it works when i run their script through the command line and append to a list, but it doesn't work at all in field calculator. I've tried to write a code for the field calculator but it didn't work either, it look like this:

```
def listCoordinates(shape):
    coordinatesList = []
    n = 0 
    for pnt in shape.getPart(n):
        xn = pnt.X
        yn = pnt.Y
        coordinatesList.append([xn , yn])
        n += 1
    return coordinatesList
```

and the expression (this function will be inside another function that return a unique value):

```
listCoordinates(!shape!)
```

Is this possible? Am i missing something? Any tips will be welcome! :)

---

It turns out that `arcpy.getPart()` do not return an array in field calculator. So you can use `arcpy.Array()` to get to the array. I was able to get what i wanted with:

```
def getCoords(shp):
    coords = []
    n = 0
    for part in arcpy.Array(shp.getPart(n)):
        for p in part:
            coords.append([p.X , p.Y])
        n += 1
    return coords
```

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea, although it's possible that your input geometry could have multiple parts. You'd also want to return the entire list instead of the first element.

Comment: To get a point from shape you have to use getObject method on it's part

Comment: Oops, i did ask to return  the first element so that i could see if the code was working, i forgot to take it out... And in this case i dont have multiple parts geometry, only single parted geometry are allowed

Answer (score 1):

**I am going to provide an alternative using the python interactive console in ArcMap.**

I find it is easier to deal with python code like this using the interactive console.  I am sure if you are very stuck with using the Field Calculator, this can be adapted to it.

```
rows = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(yourLayer, ["SHAPE@", "fieldToStoreInfo"]) 
for row in rows:
     coords = []
     for i in range(row[0].partCount):
         parts = row[0].getPart(i)
         for part in parts:
             coords.append((part.X, part.Y))
     row[1] = str(coords)
     rows.updateRow(row)
```

SHAPE@ returns a geometry object which lets you check its part count (vertices).  Then you can iterate through all the parts to get each one's X and Y values.  Append it to your list and when you return you convert the list to a string.  The value that gets stored is like:

```
[(2924327.0050581694, 10204574.257406339), (2924318.8784340024, 10204555.405738011), (2924317.0618365854, 10204533.60164775), (2924322.5132692605, 10204520.88152884), (2924331.5985529274, 10204511.796245173), (2924366.122762084, 10204511.796245173)]
```

Also, make sure your field has enough space for a long list of coordinate points.  I set mine at a crazy high number just because my test file was a set of utility lines.

Comment: What works in arcpy not always work in calculator when dealing with geometry http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158782/script-arcpy-vs-field-calculator-python-parser-behaviour-of-getpart-in-arcgi

Comment: Branco, i'll try to use this later and i tell you if it works, i also will check on FelixIP advice... Thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: The code works just like you said, but i didn't manage to adapt to field calculator, however i did get the result i wanted folowing FelixIP tip, i edited the question with it.Thanks for both of you!